# Returning distinct rows while treating NULLs as distinct

Tags: mysql

I have a table:
[image]

I need a `SELECT` statement which will return the following: for rows with the same `phoneNumber`, I want to only return the first row. For rows that are `NULL`, I want to return all of these. Tried using `DISTINCT` but that obviously doesn't work in the case of `NULL` as it will only return 1 `NULL` row. So the data I need would look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `UNION` operator to combine the result sets of two queries.

In the first query you will fetch only the rows that
have a phone number and you will use `GROUP BY` to get distinct phone numbers.

In the second query you will fetch all the rows that do not have a phone number.

Something like this should work:

```
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `phoneNumber` IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY phoneNumber
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM `table`
WHERE `phoneNumber` IS NULL
```